# z-transform help

Tags: z-transform

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

[image]

And the solutions manual states that the resolution is this one:

[image]

but I can not understand the last step, which is indicated with an arrow.
Also, how do you find the ROC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the numererator and denominator by $z^N$ and factor out (in the denominator) $z^{N-1}$.

Comment: dunno why this answer was downvoted, but i balanced it out with an upvote.

Comment: probably because I didn’t use math style font. thanks for edit.